# how to trigger "onMouseOut" from click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, vb.net

So this is a pretty simple question, but researching it, I can only find answers to more complicated situations.  Here's mine:

I have an image on a master page that when you hover over it, a panel is displayed beneath it (using css mostly) and that panel has links in it.  Because the master page is the same, clicking on those links correctly incorporates the new content page below, but the panel stays visible until you move the mouse out of the panel, and so it covers some of the content.

What I'd like is for the `onClick` event of that link to also trigger the `onMouseOut` so that when the link is clicked, the panel hides itself again, until the image is hovered over again.  I've got a decent amount of JavaScript experience, but it seems like there should be an easier way to do this... something like adding to the `li` or anchor tag an `onClick:onMouseOut()`, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to actually write it... ideas?

Comment: just call the same `function` onclick and onmouseout, no?

Comment: it's all being done via css right now, so I'm not actually calling an onClick anywhere yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simpler way...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(
    function() {
    $(this).closest(".drop").trigger(onmouseout);
    })
    });
```

This just adds the mouseout event to every anchor that's clicked...so it might be a bit of overkill, but I couldn't imagine a scenario in my page where a user would click on a link, and we would want to retain the menu open.

Comment: In terms of browser compatibility this answer is actually the most recommended one. But you did not ask for jquery-solution :)

Comment: good to know about the compatibility... I was just starting the firefox chrome etc testing... Sorry about not mentioning jquery... I'm a newb to client side scripting, so sometimes I forget to include/make distinctions...

Comment: Just a joke :) You found a solution yourself and that's the most important thing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried toggling a class on click, and using that class to remove the functionality that shows the panel on hover? So for example, add class "hide" on click. Then:

```
.panel.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: If I do that, can I immediately remove it afterwords? It's all being done via css right now, so would I be correct in thinking that adding that class would hide it, and then removing that class wouldn't technically reshow it, until I hovered over the image again?

Comment: i know it's a little hackish, but yes, that's an option.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the createElement method to overcome this problem:

```
 // Create the event.
 var eventMouseOut = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');

 // Define that the event name is 'mouseout'.
 eventMouseOut .initMouseEvent('mouseout', true, true,...);

 // Listen for the event.
 document.getElementById(...).addEventListener('click', function (e) {

   // handle click
   ...
   ...

   // dispatch mouseout-event
   document.getElementById('panel-id').dispatchEvent(eventMouseOut ); 

 }, false);
```

dispatchEvent can be called wherever you want like within a onClick-handler.
Pleasse watch out that the addEventListener is in old IE-versions not supported.
source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent

similar question and answer:

Comment: I get kind of confused about halfway in...So let me see if I understand how this would work:
I create an event with the parameter 'MouseEvents'. then call the function initMouseEvent with parameters ('mouseout', true, true) (do I need the ... for a 4th parameter?) then I could add an event listener to, say, all anchor tags... and then I could set it to listen for a click event?  and then call a function which fires the event of 'mouseout'? the first 2 steps make sense, but I'm struggling with the 2nd two... can you explain it a little more? or add some more specifics?

Comment: The Examples above are only possibalities of what you can do with costum MouseEvents. As far as I have understood you question you want to trigger another event when a click happened, right? Then I would recommend that you use the dispatchEvent-methode within you click-handler. And forget the addEventListener example.

Comment: Hope this corresponds to your need to hopefully answer your question.